# permit params array in nested attribute [active admin]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.2

How to specify **array attribute of a nested_attribute** in **permit_params** in **active admin**?

app/model/event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base    
   has_many :other_details, dependent: :destroy    
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :other_details    
end
```

app/models/other_detail.rb

```
class OtherDetail < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :event    
end
```

app/admin/event.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do    
permit_params :other_details_attributes => [:id, :detail_type, :points]    
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
    f.has_many :other_details do |ff, index|
        ff.input :detail_type
        ff.input :points, input_html: { value: (ff.object.points.join(", ").remove('%') if ff.object.points.present?)}
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting

```
params['experience']['other_details_attributes'] = 
{"0"=>{"detail_type"=>"Itinerary","points"=>"point A, point B", "id"=>"37"},
"1"=>{"detail_type"=>"Schedule","points"=>"point C, point D", "id"=>"36"}}
```

How to get this?

```
params['experience']['other_details_attributes'] = 
{"0"=>{"detail_type"=>"Itinerary", "points"=>["point A", "point B"],"id"=>"37"},
"1"=>{"detail_type"=>"Schedule", "points"=>["point C", "point D"], "id"=>"36"}}
```

**Note** -

1. I am getting **points** in **string** I need it in **array**.
2. I tried method suggested by **@xeon131**, but it led to lots of complicated code for update method.

Comment: Why are you joining points if you want it in an array?

Comment: I need to show it in this format only, to the user.

Comment: did you tried this `[:id, :detail_type, :points => [] ]` ?

Comment: I guess join is not the issue here. If I don't use join, I will still get "points"=>"[point C, point D]"  in this format in params, which is still string not array

Comment: @Vishal yes I tried this but this is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for the link. But how to use this in `active admin`

Answer (score 0):

You can override the points setter and getter method to get your desired behavior in the model.

`app/models/other_detail.rb`

```
  def points
    self[:points]&.join(",")
  end

  def points=(values)
    self[:points] = values.split(",")
  end
```

Comment: How to call this in `active admin` ?

Comment: The methods above are overriding existing methods. change your form to `ff.input :points` and the setter method will get called automatically when form is submitted

Comment: I tried the method suggested by you but this led to lots of lines of code, which could've been avoided if `[:id, :detail_type, :points => [] ]` worked.

Comment: I agree, Why is it not working? Does active admin not support it. Unfortunately, I cannot look into it properly because I do not have access to your code